# When to use v-model in vue.js?

Tags: php, vue.js

I'm using ci4 and vue.js to create a drop-down list. I'm confuse when to use a v-model and when not to use.
I try to view selected data in drop-down list. When I use a v-model, the selected  data doesn't view in my drop-down list.

`

```html
<div class="input-group mb-3" style="width: 500px;">                                    
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa-solid fa-location-dot"></i></span>
  </div>
  <select class="form-control" v-model="sel_kod_negara" :class="{'is-invalid': error.kod_negara}">
        <option value="">-Select Country-</option>
        <option :value="selected.di_kod_negara" selected>{{selected.keterangan}}</option>
        <option :value="r.kod" v-for="r in kod_negara">{{r.keterangan}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

`

the picture below show when i put the v-model

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJUc8.png)

When I delete the v-model from my attributes drop-down list, the selected data will view. It's any problem if I'm not use a v-model in my drop-down list attributes?

the picture below show when i don't put the v-model

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/scz37.png)

Any advise please? Thank you!

Comment: What is the value of `sel_kod_negara`, does it match your options ? I guess it does not exist or is null, that's why nothing is selected